# EsHadoopParsingException: Cannot parse value [15000.0] for field [transaction_value]

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have this error "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopParsingException: Cannot parse value [15000.0] for field [transaction_value]"

When I try to read ElasticSearch data with spark 2.4.7 and ElasticSearch 8.8.0

My dataframe contains a column named "transaction_value" of type "long" but last it contains data of type decimal.

Does anyone have this error?

I've tried to cast the type from long to decimal but it doesn't work, there's always this error coming back

Code for reading data from ElasticSearch

```scala
val df = spkSession.read
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("inferSchema", "false")
  .option("es.nodes", _host)
  .option("es.net.http.auth.user", login)
  .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", password)
  .option("es.net.ssl", "true")
  .option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true")
  .option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
  .option("query", s"$query")
  .load(s"$indexName")
```

Comment: `of type "long" but last it contains data of type decimal.` that's the actual error. You can't parse a decimal value as if it were an integer. You need to either modify your code to work with decimals or find out where the bad data came from